# How do I connect to Astra DB from TablePlus?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

I would like to connect to my [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) from [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/) (database GUI client). How do I configure TablePlus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prerequisites

This article assumes you have a running installation of [Tableplus](https://tableplus.com/) on your laptop or PC. It was written for MacOS but it should also work for Windows machines.

You will also need [to generate an application token](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/managing-org.html#_manage_application_tokens) and [download the secure bundle](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/secure-connect-bundle.html) for [your Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf).

### Procedure

NOTE: For simplicity, the secure connect bundle has been placed in /path/to/scb.

##### DB INFORMATION

On your laptop or PC where Tableplus is installed, unpack your secure bundle. For example:

```
$ cd /path/to/scb
$ unzip secure-connect-getvaxxed.zip
```

Here is an example file listing after unpacking the bundle:

```
/
  path/
    to/
      scb/
        ca.crt
        cert
        cert.pfx
        config.json
        cqlshrc
        identity.jks
        key
        trustStore.jks
```

Obtain information about your database from the `config.json` file. Here is an example:

```
{
  "host": "70bf8560-105f-11ec-a3ea-0800200c9a66-us-west1.db.astra.datastax.com",
  "port": 98765,
  "cql_port": 34567,
  "keyspace": "getvaxxed",
  "localDC": "us-west-2",
  "caCertLocation": "./ca.crt",
  "keyLocation": "./key",
  "certLocation": "./cert",
  "keyStoreLocation": "./identity.jks",
  "keyStorePassword": "Kga1OJ83EF2oBQYR5",
  "trustStoreLocation": "./trustStore.jks",
  "trustStorePassword": "n8F9ptJO3H7YRxTW1",
  "csvLocation": "./data",
  "pfxCertPassword": "9b3HgFChtY60m4nfJ"
}
```

We will use this information to configure Astra DB as the data source in Tableplus.

##### NEW CONNECTION

STEP 1 - In Tableplus, create a new connection and select **Cassandra** as the target database.

STEP 2 - In the **Host** and **Port** fields, use the `host` and `cql_port` values in the `config.json` above.

STEP 3 - In the **User** and **Password** fields, use the client ID and client secret from the token you created in the **Prerequisites** section of this article.

STEP 4 - In the **Keyspace** field, use the `keyspace` value in the `config.json` above.

STEP 5 - Choose `SSL VERIFY NONE` for the **SSL mode** field.

STEP 6 - For **SSL keys**, select the secure bundle files:

- `key` for Key (leave the password blank when prompted)
- `cert` for Cert
- `ca.crt` for CA Cert

Here's an example of what the Cassandra Connection dialog box should look like:

[image]

Final test
Connect to your Astra DB. If the connection was successful, you should be able to see all the tables on the left-hand side of the UI.

Here's an example output:

[image]

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!